# using OpenMP in a Qt/C++ program

Tags: c++, multithreading, api, qt, openmp

I would like to parallelize a Qt/C++ program with OpenMP, so I can compare against Qt threading tools. I have some questions.

1. What do I have to include, both in code and in project files to have OpenMP working properly?
2. Would it be painful to use OpenMP in a deliverable software project? Should each versions include updates for OpenMP and much maintenance?
3. What do you experienced as performance with OpenMP?
4. Is nested parallel work with OpenMP trustworthy?
5. Is OpenMP supported on the same platforms as Qt?

Any references would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Too many unrelated questions grouped together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *What do I have to include, both in code and in project files to have OpenMP working properly?*

   You'll have to introduce OpenMP pragmas in the code, and possibly to link against the OpenMP runtime library (which will introduce limited changes in your build system).
2. *Would it be painful to use OpenMP in a deliverable software project? Should each versions include updates for OpenMP and much maintenance?*

   I'm not sure what you mean by "painful". I know a lot of projects successfully using OpenMP. There might be some maintenance needed from time to time (but I guess this is also true for Qt).
3. *What do you experienced as performance with OpenMP?*

   More or less what should be expected of any good thread-based parallelization tool. If the workload is sufficiently heavy, OpenMP in itself should not add much overhead to your code and Amdahl's law will be your limit.
4. *Is nested parallel work with OpenMP trustworthy?*

   Yes
5. *Is OpenMP supported on the same platforms as Qt?*

   Unlike Qt, which is a framework, OpenMP support is mostly done by compilers. You might find platforms on which Qt is compilable, but where the C++ compilers don't support OpenMP. Of course, it depends on what type of platforms you target.

Comment: I've never experienced any pain using OpenMP.